# Spaghetti diagram via image/video processing?

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to come up with a simple method to obtain a spaghetti diagram from video or still images. The application would be in a production plant setting... you'd place a camera above the production floor (say a pi camera), record video. Then the video would be processed, and you'd get something that would aid you in making the diagram.

I've looked into CV object tracking and openPtrack, but it seems too complicated for what I'm looking to do. I'm thinking more along the line of taking the video, getting frames from it, and composing them into a single image which would show streaks where there's objects moving... kind of like one of those nighttime long exposure photos. In fact I figure special targets would have an IR beacon on them, so the camera would pick them up as bright streaks.

Anyway, I've been playing around with the imagemagick tools (compare/composite) which work ok for 2 frames, but when you apply them to several frames, you progressively lose the differences from the first frames. And if I do comparison in frames and then combine everything into a single image, the background areas of the images obstruct the difference marks in the next images, etc.

Anyone have any ideas on how to go about this? Or maybe I'm just reinventing the wheel and there's already something that does it you might recommend?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please read [ask].

Comment: What specifically do you want ImageMagick to do with your images? If you can explain functionally in more detail, then perhaps I can help further with an appropriate command line. The ImageMagick montage function will place a number of images together on the same image. You can also use -composite multiple times, since it only allows 2 images at a time. Or you can use -flatten to composite multiple images in one command. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/. ImageMagick will not automatically draw lines. So you will  have to use -draw "line ..." after figuring out where the lines go.